# Convert std::string::iterator to fit into boost::multi_index_container 'insert' function

Tags: c++, boost

There is this [example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/multi_index/example/hashed.cpp), specifically this part of it:

```
text_tokenizer tok(text,boost::char_separator<char>(" \t\n.,;:!?'\"-"));
  unsigned int   total_occurrences=0;
  for(text_tokenizer::iterator it=tok.begin(),it_end=tok.end();
      it!=it_end;++it){
    /* Insert the word into the container. If duplicate, wit will point to
     * the preexistent entry.
     */

    ++total_occurrences;
    word_counter::iterator wit=wc.insert(*it).first;
```

I wanted to do basically the same, but using std::string::iterator because I need to insert separate characters from a string into the container:

```
  for (std::string::iterator it=text.begin(),it_end=text.end();
       it!=it_end;++it)
  {
      word_counter::iterator wit=wc.insert(*it).first;
  }
```

I get the following error:

```
no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘char’ to ‘const value_type&’ {aka ‘const word_counter_entry&’}
  299 |   std::pair<iterator,bool> insert(const value_type& x)
      |                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

Answer (score 0):

A character is not a string. If you really want to do that conversion, you can:

```
word_counter   wc;
for (std::string::iterator it=text.begin(),it_end=text.end();
       it!=it_end;++it)
{
    char ch = *it;
    std::string str(1, ch);
    word_counter::iterator wit=wc.insert(str).first;
}
```

Note that with C++11 you can much improve this:

```
word_counter wc;
for (char ch : text) {
    auto [wit, _] = wc.emplace(std::string{1, ch});
}
```

### Simpler Frequence Histogram

However, perhaps you really want a letter-counter, so why not just: [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/nedn8q)

```
#include <array>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

using namespace std::string_view_literals;

int main() {
    std::array<size_t, 256> histogram{};
    for (char ch : "as the world turns!"sv) {
        ++histogram[ch];
    }

    fmt::print("Result: {}\n", histogram);
}
```

### Using Map

This prints only the characters seen: [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/MM1o1T)

```
#include <map>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

using namespace std::string_view_literals;

int main() {
    std::map<char, size_t> histogram;
    for (char ch : "as the world turns!"sv) {
        ++histogram[ch];
    }

    fmt::print("Result: {}\n", histogram);
}
```

Prints

```
Result: {(' ', 3), ('!', 1), ('a', 1), ('d', 1), ('e', 1), ('h', 1), ('l', 1), ('n', 1), ('o', 1), ('r', 2), ('s', 2), ('t', 2), ('u', 1), ('w', 1)}
```

### Advanced C++20: Sorting, Top-5

If you have ranges, you can add sorting and Top-N: [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/jddecb)

```
#include <map>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <ranges>

using namespace std::string_view_literals;
using Histo = std::map<char, size_t>;
using Entry = Histo::value_type;

namespace r = std::ranges;
namespace v = r::views;

int main() {
    Histo histo;
    for (char ch : "as the world turns!"sv) {
        ++histo[ch];
    }

    auto flip = histo | v::transform([](Entry& e) { return std::tuple(e.second, e.first); });
    std::vector ranking(flip.begin(), flip.end());
    std::ranges::sort(ranking, std::greater_equal<>{});

    fmt::print("Result: {}\n", ranking | v::take(5));
}
```

Prints

```
Result: {(3, ' '), (2, 't'), (2, 's'), (2, 'r'), (1, 'w')}
```

#### More Efficient

Without dynamically allocating the map: [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/9nKs59):

```
#include <map>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <ranges>

using namespace std;
using namespace string_view_literals;

namespace r = ranges;
namespace v = r::views;

int main() {
    array<size_t, 256> histo{};
    for (char ch : "as the world turns!"sv) {
        ++histo[ch];
    }

    auto flip = histo
        | v::transform([ch='\0'](size_t freq) mutable { return tuple(freq, ch++); });

    vector ranking(flip.begin(), flip.end());
    ranges::sort(ranking, greater_equal<>{});

    fmt::print("Result: {}\n", ranking | v::take(5));
}
```

Prints

```
Result: {(3, ' '), (2, 't'), (2, 's'), (2, 'r'), (1, 'w')}
```